# Different code style for committing and for working?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

Is there a way in IntelliJ to setup one codestyle for committing only and another codestyle for working?

E.g. when I reformat code locally, it would look like

```
if (true)
{
    // A
}
else
{
    // B
}
```

and the code that is being committed to everyone else would look like

```
if (true) {
    // A
} else {
    // B
}
```

without the need to manually change the code style in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA. There is [an open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-534), but the fact that it was created 13 years ago makes it clear that it's not being considered a priority (or, actually, a good idea).